# Disable Cloudwatch logs for serverless websocket app

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a WebSocket API hosted on AWS using the serverless framework.

The problem is that I am seeing 150k logs every minute, and it is costing a bunch.

The following log groups are the problem:

- /aws/apigateway/mzl9lpgzn0/production
- API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_xkkvpjzgqj/production

I have followed their docs to disable logs like so, but it is showing an error.

```
service: BotBindSocketAPI

custom:
  customDomain:
    - domainName: ${ssm:/botapi/${opt:stage}/wsName}
      stage: ${opt:stage}
      websocket: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  region: us-east-1
  logRetentionInDays: 7
  logs:
    restApi:
      accessLogging: false
      executionLogging: false
      level: ERROR
      fullExecutionData: true
    websocket: false
    frameworkLambda: false
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - "execute-api:ManageConnections"
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:**/@connections/*"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - "s3:GetObject"
        - "s3:PutObject"
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:s3:::botbind-addons/*"
  vpc:
    truncated

functions:
  websocketHandler:
    handler: handler.websocketHandler
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: $connect
          authorizer: authHandler
      - websocket:
          route: $disconnect
      - websocket:
          route: $default
      - websocket:
          route: ping
      - websocket:
          route: getBot
  authHandler:
    handler: handler.authHandler

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-domain-manager
```

Error:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

An error occurred: WebsocketsDeploymentStage - The following context variables are not supported: [$context.status] (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 4a522b6c-6ade-4f86-afcf-35017a22c30c).
```

Is this the right way to disable API logs, so I can reduce my CloudWatch costs?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For Serverless framework you will need something like this:

```
functions:
  myCloudWatchLog:
    handler: myCloudWatchLog.handler
    events:
      - cloudwatchLog:
        logGroup: '/aws/lambda/hello'
        filter: '{$.userIdentity.type = Root}'
```

Source https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudwatch-log/

Comment: Isn't the question how to disable logs, not how to filter log events?